# Difference between 1> and >

Tags: bash, shell, files, io-redirection

Is there any difference between (# comments taken from [documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html))

```
command > filename  # Docs: Redirect stdout to a file.
```

and

```
command 1> filename # Docs: Redirect stdout to file "filename."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Bash manual's section on Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output) (emphasis mine):

> Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the
>   expansion of *word* to be opened for writing on file descriptor *n*,
>   or **the standard output (file descriptor 1) if *n* is not specified**. If
>   the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is
>   truncated to zero size.

So, there is no difference between `>foo` and `1>foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Standard output is the implicit file descriptor if it isn't listed, so they're effectively the same thing. Using `1>` is not a style that I've ever seen.

```
% grep _FILENO /usr/include/unistd.h 
#define  STDIN_FILENO   0       /* standard input file descriptor */
#define STDOUT_FILENO   1       /* standard output file descriptor */
#define STDERR_FILENO   2       /* standard error file descriptor */
```

Comment: How does the shell use `unistd.h`?

Comment: The shell and most if not all programs are compiled with `unistd.h`.